# How can I mathematically model the combinatory problem?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, optimization, mathematical-modeling

I have the following problem, and I would like to model it using a mathematical formula, for a purpose of optimization problem:

let's say that I have two tasks $[T_1, T_2]$, and $3$ resources $[R_1,R_2,R_3]$, each resource has a price $P$.

I would like to find the formula which found the best combination of [task, resource], let's say the maximum combination of the following sums:

$Max$$[(T_1/P_1 + T_2/P_1), (T_1/P_1 + T_2/P_2), (T_1/P_1 + T_2/P_3), (T_1/P_2 + T_2/P_1), (T_1/P_2 + T_2/P_2), (T_1/P_2 + T_2/P_3), (T_1/P_3 + T_2/P_1), (T_1/P_3 + T_2/P_2), (T_1/P_3 + T_2/P_3)]$

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You have a classical [assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem). The wiki entry should have enough info to get you started on modeling it.

Comment: Thank you @wonko, indeed, it is an assignment problem, but here, the two tasks may be affected to the same resource if the cost is optimum, or they could affected to two different resources.